# Mocking external dependencies during load testing

Tags: node.js, performance-testing, load-testing, k6, artillery

I have a backend written in node.js that uses external APIs on some endpoints. I want to do load test without testing those external dependencies. Is it possible to mock them and how? I don't really care about the time it takes to reach the APIs and it has to be excluded from the test. The mock should be as easy as returning a plain object. Right now I've been trying to use k6 or artillery to do those tests but I had no luck on finding out how to mock. Any resources that could help me achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you tried [xk6-mock](https://github.com/szkiba/xk6-mock) k6 extension?
2. Also [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) is very powerful and easy to use. It even has [REST API](http://wiremock.org/docs/api/) so you can create mock mappings from k6 using simple HTTP calls
3. There are also online mock services like [Mockoon](https://mockoon.com/) or [BlazeMeter Mock Services](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-mock-services-in-blazemeter/)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to mock the entire http endpoint. Only services that are used inside those endpoints and the rest of the logic should stay the same. I tried xk6-mock for example but I can't see the option to mock only one part of the endpoint (call to external API)